# Create temp values in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In angular the following happened to me

```
function(){
$scope.varObj = {"name" : "john" , "age" : "20" };
$scope.tempVar1 = $scope.varObj;
$scope.tempVar2 = $scope.varObj ;
}
```

Now if i change tempVar2 automatically the value of tempVar1 is changed.

```
    function(){
     $scope.varObj = {"name" : "john" , "age" : "20" };
     $scope.tempVar1 = $scope.varObj;
     $scope.tempVar2 = $scope.varObj;
     $scope.tempVar2.name = "mathews";
     console.log($scope.tempVar1.name); 
    }
```

The output should be "john" because i am changing the value of tempVar2 not the tempVar1. But to the surprise the output is "mathews".

I tried both angular.copy and angular.extend but both produce the same output. 
Can someone please help

Comment: Show the code with angular.copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason for it to not work with `angular.copy`

Heres' a fiddle with 
[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hf2255ew/)

Answer (score 1):

It's hapening becuase of two way binding

Try like this

```
 $scope.tempVar1 = angular.copy($scope.varObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `angular.copy()` for it
By default only reference copy with assignment operator `=` which mean sharing the same memory space so if you change in any of the two object it will reflect into second one as well.

`angular.copy()` will create deep copy of the object

[DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy):-

> Creates a deep copy of source, which should be an object or an array.

```
$scope.varObj = {"name" : "john" , "age" : "20" };
     $scope.tempVar1 = angular.copy($scope.varObj);
     $scope.tempVar2 = angular.copy($scope.varObj);
     $scope.tempVar2.name = "mathews";
     console.log($scope.tempVar1.name);
```